# Why I cannot send byte data to a Android Socket app but it works great in c#

Tags: c#, android, sockets, ip

I have created a C# windows program using sockets. I can send this string to the control board I am working with

```
socketObject.ReceiveBufferSize = 500;
socketObject.SendBufferSize = 500;
socketObject.Connect("10.10.100.254", 8899);
byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin" + "\r\n");
socketObject.Send(msg);
```

this works perfectly using C# in a Windows app. But I am porting to a Android app and cannot get this to work

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(5000);
socket.setSendBufferSize(5000);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(sIP),iPort),1500);
mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

string message;
message = "admin" + "\\r\\n";
byte[] m = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
mBufferOut.println(m);
```

This does not work and I am STUCK!

Comment: Did you add the INTERNET permission to your Manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, The Actual socket "connection" to the board works. I must send the string "admin \r\n" to the board before it will accept any other commands. It keeps rejecting it. I can switch to windows program using the same computer I am developing the app with and run the windows program and it sends perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. I am not sure if it the best solution but it works!

```
char CR  = (char) 0x0D;
char LF  = (char) 0x0A;
String s = "admin" + CR + LF;
mTcpClient.sendMessage(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```